# semi-bold mathsf

Tags: fonts, bold, boldmath

I would like to use a bold (or better a semi-bold) `\mathsf` font with `mathpazo` + `eulervm`. However, using only these two packages such a possibility does not seem to exist (note that in the following table I check different (are them really different?) possibilities with the help of the `bm` package):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % especially for non-english languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % spanish,english

% AMS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usepackage{lmodern}           
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % add possibly `sc` and `osf` options
\usepackage{eulervm} % Euler math

\usepackage{bm}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rccccc}
  &\text{*}  & \text{\texttt{\textbackslash bm\{*\}}} & \text{\texttt{\textbackslash bm\{\{*\}\}}}  & \text{\texttt{\textbackslash boldsymbol}} & \text{\texttt{\textbackslash hm\{*\}}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathnormal}}   & \mathnormal{a}  & \bm{\mathrm{\mathnormal{a}}} & \bm{{\mathrm{\mathnormal{a}}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathrm{\mathnormal{a}}}   & \hm{\mathrm{\mathnormal{a}}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathrm}} & \mathrm{a}  & \bm{\mathrm{a}} & \bm{{\mathrm{a}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathrm{a}}   & \hm{\mathrm{a}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathbf}} & \mathbf{a}  & \bm{\mathbf{a}} & \bm{{\mathbf{a}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathbf{a}}   & \hm{\mathbf{a}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathsf}} & \mathsf{a}  & \bm{\mathsf{a}} & \bm{{\mathsf{a}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathsf{a}}   & \hm{\mathsf{a}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathit}} & \mathit{a}  & \bm{\mathit{a}} & \bm{{\mathit{a}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathit{a}}   & \hm{\mathit{a}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathtt}} & \mathtt{a}  & \bm{\mathtt{a}} & \bm{{\mathtt{a}}}  & \boldsymbol{\mathtt{a}}   & \hm{\mathtt{a}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathcal}} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\quad  &\text{*}  \quad& \text{\texttt{\textbackslash bm\{*\}}} \quad& \text{\texttt{\textbackslash bm\{\{*\}\}}}  \quad& \text{\texttt{\textbackslash boldsymbol}} \quad& \text{\texttt{\textbackslash hm\{*\}}}\\
 \quad  & A \quad & \bm{A}\quad & \bm{{A}} \quad & \boldsymbol{A}  \quad & \hm{A}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathnormal}} \quad  & \mathnormal{A} \quad & \bm{\mathrm{\mathnormal{A}}}\quad & \bm{{\mathrm{\mathnormal{A}}}} \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathrm{\mathnormal{A}}}  \quad & \hm{\mathrm{\mathnormal{A}}}\\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathrm}}   \quad & \mathrm{A}  \quad & \bm{\mathrm{A}}  \quad & \bm{{\mathrm{A}}}     \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}}    \quad & \hm{\mathrm{A}}  \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathbf}}   \quad & \mathbf{A}  \quad & \bm{\mathbf{A}}  \quad & \bm{{\mathbf{A}}}     \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathbf{A}}    \quad & \hm{\mathbf{A}}  \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathsf}}   \quad & \mathsf{A}  \quad & \bm{\mathsf{A}}  \quad & \bm{{\mathsf{A}}}     \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}    \quad & \hm{\mathsf{A}}  \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathit}}   \quad & \mathit{A}  \quad & \bm{\mathit{A}}  \quad & \bm{{\mathit{A}}}     \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathit{A}}    \quad & \hm{\mathit{A}}  \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathtt}}   \quad & \mathtt{A}  \quad & \bm{\mathtt{A}}  \quad & \bm{{\mathtt{A}}}     \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathtt{A}}    \quad & \hm{\mathtt{A}}  \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathcal}}  \quad & \mathcal{A} \quad & \bm{\mathcal{A}} \quad & \bm{{\mathcal{A}}}    \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}   \quad & \hm{\mathcal{A}} \\
\text{\texttt{\textbackslash mathfrak}} \quad & \mathfrak{A}\quad & \bm{\mathfrak{A}}\quad & \bm{{\mathfrak{A}}}   \quad & \boldsymbol{\mathfrak{A}}  \quad & \hm{\mathfrak{A}}\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{standalone}
```

However, after some experimenting, I discovered that if I also load `lmodern` (uncommenting the corresponding line), then I get bold versions in the `\mathsf` row. In view of all that my questions are the following:

1. Is there a proper way of obtaining bold `\mathsf` just using `mathpazo` + `eulervm`?
2. If so, is it possible to get a semi-bold `\mathsf` just using `mathpazo` + `eulervm`?
3. If not, what is the best way of obtaining semi-bold `\mathsf` with `mathpazo` + `eulervm`?
4. In case that there is no better strategy than loading `lmodern`, how can I get a semi-bold `\mathsf`?

Finally, if there is a not very long explanation on how these things work I will be very happy to hear about them. Any good reference on this is also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: macro packages can not make fonts, they can only load fonts that are available, semi-bold is not very common.